# How to connect socket.io to an external back-end with Vuejs webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, socket.io, vue.js

I'm trying to use socket.io on my Vue API, but I have the following problem:

- `Vue.use(VueSocketIO, io('localhost:5000'))` works on development but don't work on production
- `Vue.use(VueSocketIO, io())` works on production but don't work on development

Is there a way to config webpack so that it could redirect socket connection to port 5000 on development?

**main.js (client side)**

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import VueMaterial from 'vue-material'
import 'vue-material/dist/vue-material.css'

import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

// import lodash from 'lodash'
// import VueLodash from 'vue-lodash/dist/vue-lodash.min'

import io from 'socket.io-client'
import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket.io'

import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(VueMaterial)
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)
Vue.use(VueSocketIO, io('localhost:5000'))

...
```

**server.js (server side)**

```
'use strict';

const http = require('http');
const app = require('../src/app');

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.set('port', port);

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);

...
```

Comment: [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) seems relevant here.

Comment: It works for me! If you post your answer I can choose it